# How to keep the component alive when refreshing page VUEJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I have a basic VueJS Laravel application and I'm trying to achieve the followings:
When I refresh the page while being on a child component page, for example, admin is the main admin panel page and admin/product-requests is the child, when I refresh the following page it gives me the 404 Not Found error. Some help?

Have tried the `<keep-alive/>`
Here is my route file:

```
import Homepage from './components/public/home'
import master from './components/backend/master';
import Dashboard from './components/backend/Home';
import ProductRequests from './components/backend/requests/ProductRequests';
import Navbar from './components/backend/includes/Navbar';


export const routes = [
    {
        path:'/',
        component:{
            template:'Homepage'
        },
    },
    {
        path:'/admin',
        name:'master',
        component:master,
        props:true,
        children:[
            {
                path:'dashboard',
                name:'dashboard',
                component:Dashboard
            },
            {
                path:'products-requests',
                name:'productRequests',
                component:ProductRequests,
                props:true
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: `<keep-alive>` doesn't apply here because you simply cannot avoid page refresh. It sounds like your HTTP server needs to be configured to render all routes with your base index.html

Comment: any ideas to how to do it?

Comment: I am not Laravel user so not sure. Looks like it has something to do with `routes/web.php` according to this tutorial: https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel

Comment: To give you clearer understanding of the problem: Vue can change URL to anything at runtime on client-side, but when it comes to refreshing, the _server_ has to understand the route that is in the address bar

Comment: I actually had to just put the route::get('/{any}') rule and now it works fine